# sql count working days elapsed month to date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am just having a mental block - trying to find out how many weekdays have elapsed month to date in mssql.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Your question is not very detailed, but perhaps this could help:  https://it.toolbox.com/question/how-to-select-weekdays-and-weekend-data-in-mysql-query-040811

Answer (score 0):

You can create a time_dimension table and with the help of this table you can find number of days in month, number of weeks for a specific month etc

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS time_dimension;
CREATE TABLE time_dimension (
        id                      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  -- year*10000+month*100+day
        db_date                 DATE NOT NULL,
        year                    INTEGER NOT NULL,
        month                   INTEGER NOT NULL, -- 1 to 12
        day                     INTEGER NOT NULL, -- 1 to 31
        quarter                 INTEGER NOT NULL, -- 1 to 4
        week                    INTEGER NOT NULL, -- 1 to 52/53
        day_name                VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL, -- 'Monday', 'Tuesday'...
        month_name              VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL, -- 'January', 'February'...
        holiday_flag            CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'f' CHECK (holiday_flag in ('t', 'f')),
        weekend_flag            CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'f' CHECK (weekday_flag in ('t', 'f')),
        event                   VARCHAR(50),
        UNIQUE td_ymd_idx (year,month,day),
        UNIQUE td_dbdate_idx (db_date)

) Engine=MyISAM;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS fill_date_dimension;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE fill_date_dimension(IN startdate DATE,IN stopdate DATE)
BEGIN
    DECLARE currentdate DATE;
    SET currentdate = startdate;
    WHILE currentdate < stopdate DO
        INSERT INTO time_dimension VALUES (
                        YEAR(currentdate)*10000+MONTH(currentdate)*100 + DAY(currentdate),
                        currentdate,
                        YEAR(currentdate),
                        MONTH(currentdate),
                        DAY(currentdate),
                        QUARTER(currentdate),
                        WEEKOFYEAR(currentdate),
                        DATE_FORMAT(currentdate,'%W'),
                        DATE_FORMAT(currentdate,'%M'),
                        'f',
                        CASE DAYOFWEEK(currentdate) WHEN 1 THEN 't' WHEN 7 then 't' ELSE 'f' END,
                        NULL);
        SET currentdate = ADDDATE(currentdate,INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    END WHILE;
END
//
DELIMITER ;

TRUNCATE TABLE time_dimension;

CALL fill_date_dimension('1-01-01','2019-01-01');
OPTIMIZE TABLE time_dimension;
```

For Number of days in a specific month:

```
 SELECT day FROM time_dimension WHERE year = 2018 AND month = 1;
```

For Number of week in a specific month:

```
SELECT week FROM time_dimension WHERE year = 2018 AND month = 1 GROUP BY week;
```